# How to print selected continous and random columns using awk

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I would like to print 1st to 10th column, 23rd column and 27th column from ifile.txt. I can able to print 1st to 10th column using

```
awk '{n=10; for (i=1;i<=n;i++) printf "%f ", $i; print "";}' ifile.txt
```

But I can't add 23rd and 27th column to it.

I have tried with the following suggestions, still there is some problem.e.g., my ifile.txt is:

```
ifile.txt
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
```

While I use the following

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '{
n=10
for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
    a[$i]
a[$23]
a[$27]
for (k in a)
    printf "%5.1f", k, FS
print ""
}' ifile.txt
```

It gives

```
4.0 27.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0 10.0 23.0  1.0  2.0  3.0
4.0 27.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0 10.0 23.0  1.0  2.0  3.0
4.0 27.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0 10.0 23.0  1.0  2.0  3.0
4.0 27.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0 10.0 23.0  1.0  2.0  3.0
4.0 27.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0 10.0 23.0  1.0  2.0  3.0
4.0 27.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0 10.0 23.0  1.0  2.0  3.0
4.0 27.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0 10.0 23.0  1.0  2.0  3.0
```

And while I use

```
cut -d ' ' -f1-10,23,27 ifile.txt
```

It gives

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 22 26
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 22 26
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 22 26
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 22 26
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 22 26
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 22 26
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 22 26
```

I could understand this and solved by modifying

```
cut -d ' ' -f2-11,24,28 ifile.txt
```

The problem was here is a space before each starts. But I am wondering for a general way to do it so that it will not see the begining space.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your fields are delimited with space.

You can try with `cut`,

```
cut -d ' ' -f1-10,23-27 yourfile
```

**Explanation:**

```
-d - Delimiter

-f - Fields
```

Comment: Sorry! Neither of the above commands printing my desired columns. Your suggested `cut` command is printing only first 4 columns and then prinitng 11-13th columns. `awk` command printing only first row of first 4 columns and 11-13th columns.

Comment: @Kayan, what is the delimiter?  If possible, post some sample data.

Comment: data are delimited with space. 1st row of my data looks like `  0.001924  0.020849  0.052856  0.068362  0.078583  0.083061  0.082358  0.078637  0.072102  0.063320  0.054825  0.046949  0.040189  0.034489  0.029273  0.024187  0.020703  0.017581  0.014776  0.012911  0.010987  0.009702  0.008361  0.007341  0.006294  0.005629  0.005049  0.004527  0.003990  0.003517  0.003256`

Comment: The second one will only work for a single line. The first command is the right approach though.

Comment: Note you are mixing `NR` and `NF`. `NR` stands for Number of Record, that is -generally- the line number. So saying `awk 'NR>=1 && NR<=10'` you are telling `awk` to print the 10 first lines. But here it is about printing columns, no matter its line number.

Answer (score 1):

```
$del=' '
cut -d "$del" -f1-10,23,27 file
```

Comment: Sorry!! this command is not printing my desire columns. It is printing 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 11th and 13th columns.

Comment: @Kay can you share your input file?

Answer (score 1):

So as to not repeat yourself with `printf`, you could build an array of all desired fields, and loop over each.

```
{
    n=10
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
        a[$i]
    a[$23]
    a[$27]
    for (k in a)
        printf "%f%s", k, FS
    print ""
}
```

Comment: This will not work if any of the strings occur anywhere before in the line.

Comment: Yes, my mistake.  I've removed the potentially troublesome answer and replaced it with a better one.

Answer (score 1):

In Perl you can try

```
perl -lane '@F = split ();   print join(" ",@F[0..9,22..26])' input_file > output_file
```